# Type Errors when the same type is imported once from local repo and once from npm

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeerror, package.json

Let's say I have a ModuleA that depends on ModuleB similar to the following, exporting a function that takes a var of type `MyType` as parameter:

```
import { MyType } from 'moduleB'

export function someFunction(thing: MyType) {
   ... // do something
}
```

And this is my own code, with moduleA and moduleB specified as node module dependencies:

```
import { someFunction } from 'moduleA'
import { MyType } from 'moduleB'

const myVar: MyType = getSomethingOfMyType()

someFunction(myVar)
```

Calling this gets me the error

> Type error: Argument of type
> 'import(".../myProject/node_modules/moduleB/build/esm/myType").MyType' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'import(".../myProject/node_modules/moduleA/node_modules/moduleB/build/esm/myType").MyType'.

MyType is the same type in myProject and in moduleA, but because there's an additional import layer (note the longer import() path for moduleA) TS thinks that the two types are different.

How can I resolve this?

Edit: moduleA is a module that I've forked and am committing bug fixes to locally, and I'm loading the dependency from my local path instead of the remote one.
That seems to make a difference; if I change the dependency back to the remote one it works. (And i haven't touched that part of the code, the error is still there when I point it at after resetting my branch back to origin/master)

So, the problem seems to be introduced when loading it locally.
In my package.json I have that:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "moduleA" : "file:../../otherProject/packages/moduleA"  // <-- Resolved with '^1.0.0'
    ...
}
```

How can I make it work with the module checked out locally?